# Speeding up pandas dataframe sorting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a 1M lines dataframe which looks like this :

```
          osm_id  name type                                           geometry                                              coord
0        63824865  <NA>  yes  POLYGON((456136.16890988743 1755970.5608851195...  [[456136.16890988743, 1755970.5608851195], [45...
1        63823609  <NA>  yes  POLYGON((456119.225064683 1755973.9683509008,4...  [[456119.225064683, 1755973.9683509008], [4561...
2        63823760  <NA>  yes  POLYGON((456118.1026120654 1755970.7192571037,...  [[456118.1026120654, 1755970.7192571037], [456...
3        63824943  <NA>  yes  POLYGON((456118.7742944715 1755962.5968225051,...  [[456118.7742944715, 1755962.5968225051], [456...
4        63824838  <NA>  yes  POLYGON((456118.8313905121 1755958.1743216205,...  [[456118.8313905121, 1755958.1743216205], [456...
...           ...   ...  ...                                                ...                                                ...
935472  252279950  <NA>  yes  POLYGON((536613.743270669 1879648.1538262032,5...  [[536613.743270669, 1879648.1538262032], [5366...
935473  252280378  <NA>  yes  POLYGON((536596.8950417594 1879676.132606462,5...  [[536596.8950417594, 1879676.132606462], [5366...
935474  252279973  <NA>  yes  POLYGON((536327.8190424527 1879851.7032969017,...  [[536327.8190424527, 1879851.7032969017], [536...
935475  252280112  <NA>  yes  POLYGON((536334.1224137093 1879862.7636976265,...  [[536334.1224137093, 1879862.7636976265], [536...
935476  252280088  <NA>  yes  POLYGON((536621.6363744448 1879681.4464025,536...  [[536621.6363744448, 1879681.4464025], [536628...

[935477 rows x 5 columns]
```

In my coord column, i have several xy points in a list and I want to sort by the distance to a XYPt point.

Sorting my 1M lines dataframe is long (3min39s). How could I speed up the sorting?

My sorting function looks like this :

```
def sort_dataframe_by_dist(dataframe, column, XYPt):
    sort_ixs = sorted(
        np.arange(len(dataframe)),
        key=lambda i: (
            (dataframe.iloc[i][column][0][1] - XYPt[1]) ** 2
            + (dataframe.iloc[i][column][0][0] - XYPt[0]) ** 2
             )** (1 / 2))
    return pd.DataFrame(
        columns=list(dataframe), data=dataframe.iloc[sort_ixs].values)
```

Comment: For one, get rid of the `** (1 / 2)` – the sorting result is the same for distance squared and just distance.

Comment: Secondly, you can micro-optimize things a little by destructuring `XYPt` outside the key function: `xypt0, xypt1 = XYpt`, and then use those variables in the key function.

Comment: thank you, i've tried to remove **(1/2) : it takes now 3min13s instead of 3min39s

Comment: if you use a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame`, I bet you'll have access to optimized geometric operations implemented in C or Cython